# How do I get "wget" for Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, command-line

There's no `wget` command. How do I get it?

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively, if you don't need `wget` specifically, Snow Leopard does come with `curl` which does many of the same things.

E.g., fetching your flair via `wget`:

```
wget http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/flair/2726.png
```

vs. fetching it with `curl`:

```
curl -O http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/flair/2726.png
```

Notably lacking from `curl` is `wget`'s `--mirror` option, but it does have nifty fetching with patterns, which handles many of the same problems:

```
# Fetch flair images for users 2726 through 2730
curl -O http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/flair/[2726-2730].png
```

Answer (score 8):

You will need to install Xcode with Unix Dev Support, then you can download and compile the source, or try macports, or homebrew.

`$ brew install wget`

`$ sudo port install wget`

Or you could try a graphical form which includes wget, like http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/24787/cocoawget

Comment: I have Xcode installed, but where can I get the unix dev support? Could you give me step by step instructions ?

Comment: http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/6490/capturadepantalla201004pd.png When installing xcode there should be a checkbox, just run through the installer again. The next part is installing either macports or homebrew https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew http://www.macports.org/install.php either of these package managers will allow you to download wget with ease once their are installed.

Comment: Call me dumb, but do you have to pay the annual $99 fee to be part of the Mac Developer program to get Xcode?

Comment: You are not dumb at all, unfortunately apple changed around xcode 4 so its either 5 bucks for the package or 99 to be in the dev program. Its annoying because all we want are the OSS headers and stuff. But if you have your original os x dvd you can install xcode right off of there. http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.xcode.html

Comment: Just as a note - this changed back very soon after so you don't need to pay

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Michael Granger's answer: `curl` (included on all Snow Leopard installs) is really quite powerful, and can do a lot of what `wget` does (and a number of things it doesn't).

But, as noted on the [curl FAQ](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#What_is_curl_not):

> 1.3 What is curl not?
>
> Curl is not a wget clone. That is a
>   common misconception. Never, during
>   curl's development, have we intended
>   curl to replace wget or compete on its
>   market. Curl is targeted at
>   single-shot file transfers.
>
> Curl is not a web site mirroring
>   program. If you want to use curl to
>   mirror something: fine, go ahead and
>   write a script that wraps around curl
>   to make it reality (like curlmirror.pl
>   does).
>
> ...

(For reference, [here's that curlmirror.pl script](http://curl.haxx.se/programs/curlmirror.txt))

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use either homebrew or macports there is a great set of [instructions here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/22/install-wget-mac-os-x/), reproduced below (using a slightly more up-to-date version of wget).

*These instructions require both Xcode and the command line tools to be installed.*

First, use curl to download the latest wget source :

```
curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.14.tar.gz
```

Next we use tar to uncompress the files you just downloaded:

```
tar -xzf wget-1.14.tar.gz
```

Use cd to change to the directory:

```
cd wget-1.14
```

Configure with the appropriate `–with-ssl` flag to prevent a “GNUTLS not available” error:

```
./configure --with-ssl=openssl
```

Build the source:

```
make
```

Install wget, it ends up in `/usr/local/bin/`:

```
sudo make install
```

Confirm everything worked by running wget:

```
wget --help
```

Clean up by removing wget source files when finished:

```
cd .. && rm -rf wget*
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest and painless way to get wget is to install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). In fact, the very home page says:

> Homebrew is the easiest and most flexible way to install the UNIX tools Apple didn't include with OS X.

and their example is:

```
$ brew install wget
```

;)