# How to uninstall wget

Tags: macos, mac, unix

I recently installed wget on my Mac using the instructions listed here: http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/22/install-wget-mac-os-x/
and lorcan's instructions here: [How do I get "wget" for Snow Leopard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12665/how-do-i-get-wget-for-snow-leopard)

However, I realized that I installed an outdated version of wget.

Is there an easy way to uninstall wget from my system?

Comment: If you install wget with Homebrew, it should replace the old version.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you installed `wget` in the first place.

- If you installed directly from source, run `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/wget`
- If you installed via Homebrew, run `brew uninstall wget` (or just use `brew upgrade wget` to install the most recent version)